# node-gyp rebuild error in nodejs

Tags: node.js, makefile, node-gyp

I have installed nodejs v0.8.11 with node-gyp v0.9.5 but when I try to install other modules that need to be compiled, I get the following error:

```
# npm install net-ping
npm install net-ping
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/net-ping
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/net-ping
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-socket
npm http 408 https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-socket
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-socket
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-socket

> raw-socket@1.1.4 install /root/testNode/node_modules/net-ping/node_modules/raw-socket
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/root/testNode/node_modules/net-ping/node_modules/raw-socket/build'
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make: Leaving directory `/root/testNode/node_modules/net-ping/node_modules/raw-socket/build'
net-ping@1.1.4 node_modules/net-ping
âââ raw-socket@1.1.4
```

The same module was installed with the same version, on another machine. What can cause such problem?!

Comment: Can you check it was the same version of raw-socket?

Comment: yes it was this version (1.1.4) in the package.json

Answer (score -1):

As I see, npm is unable to download raw-socket/package.json . looks like raw-socket is broken and you need to contact the developers and ask them to fix it.